# The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.table.core.windows.net'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I have created a cloud service to get error logs and hosted it on Azure. It is working perfectly there, but when i host the same application on IIS, it is giving
error.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'xxx.table.core.windows.net'

I am not supposed to show a code piece. Also i know that a duplicate post exists at [The remote name could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901340/the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved), but the answers there couldn't remove my error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: an azure table is like a rest service endpoint.. can you hit the same URL from fiddler or a Rest client on that same box? if no, it has nothing to do with IIS, and maybe connectivity or DNS issues.

Comment: @RajaNadar  But the same code is working well on localhost as well as Azure

Comment: Agree with Raja. Also please check if there's a Firewall/Proxy in between that may be blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to host on a colleague's computer. If it works there, re-install IIS

Answer (score 0):

If the code works on localhost and on Azure, but doesn't work on IIS, it mostly smells of a proxy issue. (since connectivity/DNS resolution will affect all scenarios on the same box) Proxy is something that behaves differently between IIS Express and IIS etc.

So find out if you use a proxy and if you do, add that info to the web.config.

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy usessystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="https://myproxy" 
         autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="True" />
 </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

The proxy might be interfering with the request.

Comment: I tried it. Now it gives an error The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.